# create a JPA1 abstract class findAll method from entity class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Using an `EntityManager` in an abstract class, I am trying to create a function that returns a list of all the results in a table from the entity class. Each table has its own persistence class that inherits from the abstract class. So far I have:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    ...

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
}
```

That works for JPA 2.0 but I just discovered that my server is restricted to JPA 1.0 which doesn't support `getCriteriaBuilder()` or `createQuery(CriteriaQuery cq)`

Is there a way I can re-factor my code to do relatively the same thing with a mechanism that exists in JPA 1.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    return (List<T>) getEntityManager().createQuery(
        "select e from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " e")
        .getResultList();
}
```

Note that it won't work if you override logical entity names (`@Entity(name = ...)`), but it's not a common case in practice.

Comment: Thanks. They syntax works, but what does this look like if I'm trying to count the rows? Would I just add `COUNT(*)` in front of the first `e` as in `select COUNT(*) e from NHDDEVL.CANDIDATE e`?

Comment: @itslittlejohn: You should use the alias itself in `count` clause: `select count(e) from ... e`

Comment: Thanks again. I am unfamiliar with JPA so pardon my ignorance, but it does not appear to work if I test the query against the DB2 database manually: `select COUNT(e) from NHDDEVL.CANDIDATE e`. Will it only work through JPA?

Comment: DB2 (or database in general) is not at all aware of JPQL queries. JPQL is query language specific to JPA. JPQL queries are translated to SQL by your JPA provider (Hibernate for example) and SQL is executed against database via JDBC driver.